# Checkbox styling

Tags: css

Is there a way to style a checkbox and a label with border, so the user can see only the label (the checkbox is hidden), and when the user clicks on the label, the label will change the color of the background and the text? This click should also work as clicking on the checkbox.
If there is a way, how should I do this?

or

How to hide the checkbox and leave only the label do the work with changing colors?

Comment: Will the checkbox value be submitted as part of a form?

Comment: yes, it will be submitted. I am also using jsf.

Comment: Didn't exactly understand what you were trying to do, but it seems it can easily be done using javascript. Please explain yourself clearer so I can help you.

Comment: @Pavel, Updated version of [accepted answer](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/kb67J/3/), you may like it.

Comment: You can use a plugin like [prettycheckboxes](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/) or design your own [here](http://csscheckbox.com/) (it's a cross-browser css checkbox generator and easy to generate) and then download the generated code or build one from the scratch using the help of [this article](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them side to side (*in html structure*) and use the [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Something like this

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" />
<label for="box1">checkbox #1</label>
```

css

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    color:red;
}
```

you could style the label (*2nd rule*) as you want of course..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kb67J/1/

Comment: +1, really nice work, i think it's also possible to use background images on label and changing the image on checked.

Comment: [Just a modified version of this answer](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/kb67J/3/), I really like the idea, thanks man :-)

Comment: I [wrote a more in-depth tutorial](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs) about how to customize checkboxes and radios, as well as create on/off switches if you want to learn it in more detail